# Unable to point CNAME of subdomain of my website to it's tumblr blog in plesk

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, subdomain, cname-record

I created a tumblr blog for my website. And I want to host it on blog.mywebsite.com subdomain. Tumblr says that I should add CNAME instead of A Records to domains.tumblr.com. But the problem is that the Plesk Control Panel is showing this error when I add a CNAME:
[image]

Following are my DNS records:

[image]

Please tell me what is wrong with my records?

Comment: You need to fill the 'Domain name', Can't have CNAME record that points nothing to something.

Comment: @HrvojeŠpoljar but I want it at blog.mywebsite.com. So with what should I fill it?

Comment: what you said; try leaving first field blank and after blog; put mywebsite

Comment: Remove all entries regarding the `blog` subdomain and make it a single `CNAME` record,  except you want a separate mail server handling the mail for the blog.

Comment: @SvW based on the `NS` records and the error message I get the distinct feeling that this is actually the zone apex.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `blog.example.com` is a zone of its own, which appears to be one of the reasons why the instructions do not work in your case.

The problem here is that a `CNAME` record is not allowed to coexist with other records and at the zone apex there must be at least `SOA` and `NS` records (in your case you also have `MX`, `TXT` and `A` records).

Only if `blog.example.com` could be a part of the `example.com` zone AND the other records that currently exist at `blog.example.com` are not actually necessary you could do as the instructions say and add that `CNAME` record.

If, however, `blog.example.com` has to be a zone of its own or if you need to have the `MX` or `TXT` records for it, then a `CNAME` record is not an option for you.
In that case you may want to look into DNS hosting that has aliasing functionality, where you can set it up so that they behind the scenes regularly look up `A` and `AAAA` for a specified name and publishes that into your zone as the original record type (`A`/`AAAA`).